# SQLAlchemy: If not committing a select query it will rollback by default, why?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, pycord

I'm trying to use the AsyncSession of SQLAlchemy for a discord bot and the issue is that when doing a simple select query using async_session() it will rollback by default if there is no session.commit(). Why? I tried following [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html) but I dind't find the solution. Here is the code:

db/database.py

```py
""" Creates a simple sqlalchemy connection to a sqlite db """
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base


# Database config
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_async_engine(f'sqlite+aiosqlite:///db/taskbot.db', echo=True)
async_session = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

db/queries.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import select
from db.schemas import Users
from db.database import async_session


async def print_users() -> None:
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(select(Users))
        db_users = result.scalars().all()

        for u in db_users:
            print(u)
        
        # This commit shouldn't be here but if there is no commit the function rollbacks by default for some reason
        await session.commit()
```

This is the code snippet that calls the function, this is inside a py-cord command because I'm using the db in a discord bot

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from discord.commands.context import ApplicationContext
from db import queries


class Debug(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @discord.command(name="debug_async_db")
    async def debug_async_db(self, ctx: ApplicationContext):
        await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        await queries.print_users()
        await ctx.respond("Users printed in console")
```

Thanks!

Comment: The general rule is that if you don't commit() you rollback. Although with only select queries its not clear what you are worried about here.

Comment: I thought rollback should only be used when transactions fail, not in simple select queries where there is no .commit(), thanks!